# How do you spy on AngularJS's $timeout with Jasmine?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, spy

I am trying to spy on $timeout so that I can verify that it has not been called. Specifically, my production code (see below) calls $timeout as a function, not an object:

```
$timeout(function() { ... })
```

and not

```
$timeout.cancel() // for instance
```

Jasmine, however, requires an object to be spied upon, like this:

```
spyOn(someObject, '$timeout')
```

I don't know what 'someObject' would be though.

I am using Angular mocks, if that makes any difference.

Edit: The relevant production code I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
EventHandler.prototype._updateDurationInOneSecondOn = function (call) {
    var _this = this;
    var _updateDurationPromise = this._$timeout(function () {
            call.duration = new Date().getTime() - call.startTime;
            _this._updateDurationInOneSecondOn(call);
        }, 1000);
    // ... more irrelevant code
}
```

In the specific test scenario I am trying to assert that $timeout was never called.

Edit 2: Specified clearly that I am using $timeout as a function, not an object.

Comment: can you post an example of the code you are testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular `$timeout` is a service that executes/calls a function. The request to "spy" `$timeout` is a bit odd being the case that what it is doing is executing X function in Y given time. What I would do to spy this services is to "mock" the timeout function and inject it in your controller something like:

```
 it('shouldvalidate time',inject(function($window, $timeout){

        function timeout(fn, delay, invokeApply) {
            console.log('spy timeout invocation here');
            $window.setTimeout(fn,delay);
        }

//instead of injecting $timeout in the controller you can inject the mock version timeout
        createController(timeout);

// inside your controller|service|directive everything stays the same 
/*      $timeout(function(){
           console.log('hello world');
            x = true;
        },100); */
        var x = false; //some variable or action to wait for

        waitsFor(function(){
            return x;
        },"timeout",200);

...
```

Comment: I suppose this will work. However, I have chosen spying on a public function in my controller that is executed at the same time as the $timeout call. I did this to make the test code much simpler.

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen what you said was your solution was not your original question. This is how your spy timeout. I think it is the answer to your question. Do you agree?

Comment: You are right, I'll mark the solution as answered. I was hesitant marking the answer as a solution, because it uses a mock and not a jasmine spy the way I was hoping for, but it is a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into the same problem and ended up decorating the $timeout service with a spy.

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$timeout', function($delegate) {
        return sinon.spy($delegate);
    });
}));
```

Wrote more about why this works [here](http://rudickulous.com/post/75310347493/spying-on-angulars-timeout-service).

Comment: Nice suggestion. I suppose one should be able to replace sinon.spy(...) with jasmine.createSpy('$timeout') (not sure about what the argument means), though I haven't tested this.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to say return jasmine.createSpy($delegate). In this case, $delegate is the original $timeout function.

Comment: Nice, I came to a similar conclusion when trying to test code very similar to your use case. Though, I wanted the ngMock functions applied on $timeout to still exist which was pretty simple to do. I'll edit your post and put in what I did.

Comment: Edit was rejected, but if anyone is interested in the changes made to preserve the ngMock $timeout decorator take a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/Sedushi/b2a678b6f5e2d2fdfe9d.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
var element, scope, rootScope, mock = {
    timeout : function(callback, lapse){
        setTimeout(callback, lapse);
    }
};

beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$timeout', function($delegate) {
      return function(callback, lapse){
          mock.timeout(callback, lapse);
          return $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    });
}));
describe("when showing alert message", function(){

    it("should be able to show message", function(){
        rootScope.modalHtml = undefined;
        spyOn(mock, 'timeout').and.callFake(function(callback){
            callback();
        });
        rootScope.showMessage('SAMPLE');

        expect(rootScope.modalHtml).toBe('SAMPLE');

    });

});
```